# ¿Como puedo llamar un componente varias veces en otro componente pero pasarle diferentes variables en angular?

Tags: angular

*Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de angular para el cual tengo un componente en el cual estoy llamando varias veces un modal a este modal le paso el titulo y la descripcion sin embargo cuando lo voy a asignar el valor a estas variables siempre me toma el valor de la primera llamada*

Componente en html

```
  <div class="tabla" *ngIf="hayAsociacionesAEliminar">
    <h1>Asociacion</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header">Nombre</th>
          <th class="table-header">NIT</th>
          <th class="table-header">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let asociacion of asociacionesEliminar">
          <td>{{asociacion?.nombre}}</td>
          <td>{{asociacion?.nit}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" >Eliminar</button>
            <app-modal-confirmacion 
              [titulo]="'Eliminar'"
              [descripcion]="'¿Estás seguro de desea eliminar la asociacion?'"
              (confirmacion)="eliminar(mensajeEliminarAsociacion)"> 
            </app-modal-confirmacion>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 

  <div class="tabla" *ngIf="hayNecesidadAEliminar">
    <h1>Proyectos</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header">Nombre</th>
          <th class="table-header">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let proyecto of necesidadEliminar">
          <td>{{proyecto?.proyecto.nombre}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Eliminar</button>
            <app-modal-confirmacion 
              [titulo]="'Eliminar'"
              [descripcion]="'¿Estás seguro de desea eliminar el proyecto?'"
              (confirmacion)="eliminarProyecto(proyecto?.proyecto.id)"> 
            </app-modal-confirmacion>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

como se puede ver en el codigo estyo llamando dos veces el modal-confirmacion yo yo le doy click en el boton eliminar del proyecto me muestra es el mensaje que se encuentra en la tabla de eliminar usuario

Answer (score 0):

¿podrías adjuntar también el archivo .ts?

De todas formas, lo que veo es que pasas el mismo texto en las dos modales, lo único que cambias es el método de eliminar.

También podría ser que no estuvieras destruyendo el componente de la modal y estuvieras tan solo mostrando y ocultando el mismo.

Pero como te digo, deberías adjunar el código .ts